# Querying from mysql tables from outside the mysql directory?

Tags: mysql

Is there any way that I can query, using jdbc, mysql tables that are in a directory outside of the mysql root directory,or will I have to move them into a database folder inside the root mysql directory? I haven't found anything whilst searching Google.

Comment: The question does not make sense - MySql does not have directories. Perhaps you need to look up `use` - but that is just a guess as to what you mean.

Comment: classic myIsam tables use three files per directory and directory is the database. InnoDB uses the directory but not the files with default settings.

Answer (score 0):

No. Either move the database files into the directory under the MySQL root or start the MySQL with different root settings.

Comment: Some time ago it was possible to create a symlink pointing to a different location but I presume it's been removed due to security concerns.